# How to make ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames on own control's Background work from code-behind?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, code-behind, wpf-animation

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic, keyframes-based color animation of my own custom ToggleButton's Background property (WPF custom control inheriting a ToggleButton). I need the animation to have its duration and colors (from/to) customizable at runtime, so I have exposed three dependency properties to alter these parameters using binding in XAML. When value of either of them changes, I update the animation to be fired when Blinking (bool DP) is set to true.

I tried following approach:

```
public class CommandAndActivationButton : ToggleButton
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlinkingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Blinking", typeof(bool), typeof(CommandAndActivationButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnBlinkingChanged));

    internal static readonly DependencyProperty BlinkingDurationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BlinkingDuration", typeof(Duration), typeof(CommandAndActivationButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(Duration), OnAnimationParametersChanged));
    internal static readonly DependencyProperty BlinkAnimationColorBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BlinkAnimationColorBrush", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(CommandAndActivationButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush), OnAnimationParametersChanged));
    internal static readonly DependencyProperty InitialAnimationColorBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InitialAnimationColorBrush", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(CommandAndActivationButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush), OnAnimationParametersChanged));

    private ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames m_BackgroundAnimation;

    static CommandAndActivationButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(CommandAndActivationButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CommandAndActivationButton)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the button should currently be blinking.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Blinking
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(BlinkingProperty);
        set => SetValue(BlinkingProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Duration (period) of the blinking animation.
    /// </summary>
    public Duration BlinkingDuration
    {
        get => (Duration)GetValue(BlinkingDurationProperty);
        set => SetValue(BlinkingProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Color for use in blinking animation (i.e. the "to" color of the animation).
    /// </summary>
    public SolidColorBrush InitialAnimationColorBrush
    {
        get => (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(InitialAnimationColorBrushProperty);
        set => SetValue(InitialAnimationColorBrushProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Color for use in blinking animation (i.e. the "to" color of the animation).
    /// </summary>
    public SolidColorBrush BlinkAnimationColorBrush
    {
        get => (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(BlinkAnimationColorBrushProperty);
        set => SetValue(BlinkAnimationColorBrushProperty, value);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        if (!Blinking) { return; }
        StartAnimation();
    }

    private static void OnBlinkingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is CommandAndActivationButton c)) { return; }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            c.StartAnimation();
        }
        else
        {
            c.StopAnimation();
        }
    }

    private static void OnAnimationParametersChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is CommandAndActivationButton c)) { return; }

        // Make sure we have enough data to create animation
        if (c.BlinkAnimationColorBrush == null ||
            c.InitialAnimationColorBrush == null ||
            c.BlinkingDuration == default) { return; }

        c.m_BackgroundAnimation = new ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        {
            Duration = c.BlinkingDuration,
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
            AutoReverse = true,
            KeyFrames = new ColorKeyFrameCollection
            {
                new DiscreteColorKeyFrame(c.InitialAnimationColorBrush.Color, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.0)),
                new DiscreteColorKeyFrame(c.BlinkAnimationColorBrush.Color, KeyTime.FromPercent(1.0))
            }
        };
    }

    private void StartAnimation()
    {
        Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, m_BackgroundAnimation);
    }

    private void StopAnimation()
    {
        Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, null);
    }
}
```

Other than this animation, the button also has a number of data triggers that change its Background when toggled (IsChecked = true), on mouse hover etc., but as far as I know those behaviors are overridden while an animation is running, so I should get the behavior I want... but I don't (although StartAnimation() is called correctly at runtime).

I have already tried to achieve the same using a single animation in pure-XAML but seems to be impossible as all the animations properties in XAML need to be static (otherwise I get a "Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads" error connected to animation being a Freezable).

Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
It does not even run with hard-coded duration and colors, like below (minimum example: setting Blinking to true correctly causes a call to StartAnimation() on the button, but nothing happens with the button's background):

```
public class CommandAndActivationButton : ToggleButton
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlinkingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Blinking", typeof(bool), typeof(CommandAndActivationButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnBlinkingChanged));

    static CommandAndActivationButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(CommandAndActivationButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CommandAndActivationButton)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the button should currently be blinking.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Blinking
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(BlinkingProperty);
        set => SetValue(BlinkingProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnBlinkingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is CommandAndActivationButton c)) { return; }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            c.StartAnimation();
        }
    }

    private void StartAnimation()
    {
        var animation = new ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        {
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
            AutoReverse = true,
            KeyFrames = new ColorKeyFrameCollection
            {
                new DiscreteColorKeyFrame(Colors.Blue, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.0)),
                new DiscreteColorKeyFrame(Colors.Yellow, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.5)),
                new DiscreteColorKeyFrame(Colors.Blue, KeyTime.FromPercent(1.0))
            }
        };
        Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
    }
}
```

The corresponding ControlTemplate of that button looks like this (simplified):

```
 <!-- Main button template -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CommandAndActivationButton}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CommandAndActivationButton">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <!-- Stuff (with not set/transparent background) -->
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
                    </Trigger>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
       <!-- Not important -->
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The background's brush color does not animate, like if I did not start animation at all.

Comment: Could you please remove the irrelevant parts from your question? It seems pointless to tell us about all these additional properties that modify the animation when it does not even run. Try to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Also make sure that the Background property is actually used in the ControlTemplate of the ToggleButton. There is usually some element that uses a highlight brush when the Button is pressed or checked.

Comment: Please see the recent update to my question: I posted minimum example + Background-related parts of the template.

Comment: Why is the Binding of the Background property TwoWay? That seems pointless. Use `<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">`. Besides that, you are trying to animate the Color property of a Brush that is implicitly created by a BrushConverter instance. You should instead explicitly assign a SolidColorBrush to the Background property: `<Setter Property="Background"><Setter.Value><SolidColorBrush Color="Gray"/></Setter.Value></Setter>`

Comment: Done, but this changed nothing. Animation started on that Background brush does not change the background. Could it be something wrong with the StartAnimation method?

Comment: I tried your recent code, but even the SolidColorBrush from the Background setter cannot be animated because it is frozen. Otherwise it is working, e.g. with `Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);` in a CommandAndActivationButton constructor. Be aware that the Background property must be set before Blinking is set to true.

Comment: @Clemens Bingo! Background's brush was frozen (no idea why). I added following as the first like of StartAnimation (to provide a non-frozen brush to animate on): `Background = new SolidColorBrush(InitialAnimationColorBrush.Color);` Animations started working instantly. Please post your comment above as an answer suggestion. I will mark it as answer.